# About CPA or CCA security proof

Tags: provable-security

Recently reading about CPA, CCA safety security proof.
After reading a few papers, the author is in the process of proof. The challenger maintains some lists. I really don’t understand why the challenger wants to maintain some lists, and some of the following steps need to check the list, and some do not need to check?

For example, the security proof of this paper (Thm. phase1)
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8662560

Comment: Interesting question, but it could be enhanced by providing more details about where the lists are introduced and your own thoughts about it.

Comment: Would this be your answer at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72662/82720?

Comment: @CloudCho 
Thank you for your answer, but it seems not. I want to know why the challenger maintains some lists or table on the paper. What is the intention?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes
It is currently speculated to maintain the consistency of the query